# Undefined variable Express Js - Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to build an API with node js. 
i post the data using postman.

[image: postman - post data using postman]

I don't know why, every time I post the data, I got nothing.

Here is my code :

```
let router = require('express').Router();
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let db = require('./queries');
router.use(bodyParser.json()); 
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 

router.post('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.send('post data ' + req.body.clinic_name)
});
```

req.body.clinic_name has no value, thats why it will undefined data.
i try clinic_name, address, phone, and fax. all of them returning undefined data.

please help me to fix this issue.
thank you.

Comment: which variable is undefined?

Comment: `{} != false` - your `if (!req.body)` will fail for an empty object.

Comment: Unrelated, but I'm unclear why you're returning the string `"res.sendStatus(400)"`, is that just some sort of temporary debugging thing?

Comment: yes its temporary. the one thing that i dont understand, i cant use req.body.something to catch any data. can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" tab in POSTMAN or you can make sure your client has header '"Content-Type: "application/json"', and send a raw json

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you have sent the data `res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.clinic_name)` first and then printing in `console.log(req.body);`

It should be like

`console.log(req.body);
res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.clinic_name)`